# #define: why uppercase?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macros, c-preprocessor

When defining a macro (e.g. `#define BALL`). Why do people use uppercase letters? I can write something like `#define ball`. It is not in uppercase, but it works.

Comment: The use of uppercase for macros is a naming convention. The preprocessor can handle any case (upper, lower, mixed) in macro names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's convention. It makes reading and understanding code easier. It's not required, but recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you use `_` for long variable names ? And why don't you just name variables as `a or b` because It is easy to understand and debug.

Using a variable name such as `TotalHeight` makes more sense than simple `i`. Some people even prefix the data type such as `Int_TotalHeight`. Its easy to maintain the code.

To answer your question, people use it for more understanding. Usually

1)To differentiate the variable name and macro name

```
 #define MAX 45 // easy to understand, it is a macro
 int max=45;
```

2)To differentiate the function from a macro. Say

```
 #define MULT(x, y) (x) * (y) 
 int mult(int,int);
```

Comment: Your welcome @nicael and more specifically macros are constants . Constants are usually represented in uppercase :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another question from today: [Can't figure out this "called object is not a function" C time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273402/cant-figure-out-this-called-object-is-not-a-function-c-time-error). In this the OP did `#define time (24 * 60 * 60)` and was surprised when `time(something)` wouldn't compile.

Pretty much nothing standard in C is all upper-case so by making your macros all upper-case, you can avoid collisions. Since the pre-processor is just doing token substitution, the collisions typically yield non-obvious or undetected errors.

Comment: The reason for the lack of collision is not that the standard doesn't use upper-case. It's because the standard prefixes those upper-cases with `_` and then reserves them.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a custom. You can write both in uppercase and lowercase.