# Can't figure out this "called object is not a function" C time error

Tags: c, function, object, time

So for part of my school assignment, I need to find the current time, and i used this as a reference:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/ 
I tried to copy what they did, but I keep getting this error:

```
l8stat.c:33: error: called object '15552000' is not a function
```

This is the line:

```
time(&current_time);
```

I really don't understand why this is happening when I'm doing the same thing as the example.

Here's my code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define SEC_PER_DAY (24 * 60 * 60)
#define time (SEC_PER_DAY*180)

 void print_data(char *path ){
   setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "en_US");
   struct stat *new=malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
   char linkname[PATH_MAX + 1];
   int status=lstat(path, new);
   if(status==0){
      printf("%.6o  %9d ",new->st_mode,
         new->st_size );
  }
  else{
     fprintf (stderr, "l8stat: %s: %s\n",
           path, strerror (errno));
 }

 time_t current_time;
 struct tm *local_time;
 time(&current_time);
 local_time=localtime(&current_time);
 char buffer[50];


 if(current_time-new->st_mtime<=time ){
    strftime(buffer,50,"%b %e %R",new->st_mtime);
    puts(buffer);
 } else{
     strftime(buffer,50,"%b %e  %Y",new->st_mtime);
     puts(buffer);
   }

 ssize_t retval = readlink (path, linkname, sizeof linkname);
   if(retval >=0){
      linkname[retval < PATH_MAX + 1 ? retval : PATH_MAX] = '\0';
      printf ("%s -> \"%s\"\n", path, linkname);
   }

 printf(" %s",path);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int exit_status=EXIT_SUCCESS;
  for(int argi = 1; argi <argc; ++argi){
     if(argc!=2)  ;
     print_data(argv[argi]);
     printf("\n");
  }

  return exit_status;
 }
```

Comment: You missed great feeling, when you managed to fix your own bug. :) Before asking a question try to debug your code at least for a hour yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You `#define time (SEC_PER_DAY*180)`, then later you call `time(&current_time);'

The preprocessor will expand

```
time(&current_time);
```

as per your `#define:`:

```
(SEC_PER_DAY*180)(&current_time);
```

and then

```
(24*60*60*180)(&current_time);
```

Note that this happens before the actual compiler sees anything (the preprocessor runs before the compiler).  So as far as the compiler is concerned, you're trying to call `24*60*60*180` = `15552000`.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. I feel so stupid now. I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: This can happen easily with the preprocessor.  It helps to use only `ALL_CAPS` names for preprocessor macros, and to not use those names for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The line `#define time (SEC_PER_DAY*180)` at the top causes all occurrences of the word "`time`" in the code to be replaced with `(SEC_PER_DAY*180)`, which then becomes `((24 * 60 * 60)*180)`, which evaluates to `15552000`.  Thus, when you try to call the `time` function later, what the compiler actually sees is `15552000(&current_time)`, which is an error.  The solution is simple, and applies to all code, not just this case: *don't name anything after standard functions* — change the `#define time` to use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
#include <time.h>
```

is defining some time variable that you redefine with your

```
#define time (SEC_PER_DAY*180)
```

and that's where the problem is, change that define name and it will work.